# Entity is not weaved. Eclipselink 2.1 + Dynamic Weaving

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink

I have a Java EE application that is running on tomcat with a couple of entity classes and using eclipselink 2.1 and jpa 2.0.
The entities are EmailNotification and EmailNotificationQueueRow.

```
@Entity
public class EmailNotification implements Serializable, IEntity<Integer> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "emailGen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "emailGen", sequenceName = "SQ_EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS", allocationSize=1)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
private Integer emailId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_SUBJECT")
private String emailSubject;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_BODY")
private String emailBody;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SENT_FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS")
private String sentFromEmailAddress;
@Column(name = "SEND_TO_ORG_ID")
private Integer sendToOrgId;
@Column(name = "SEND_TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS")
private String sendToEmailAddress;
@Column(name = "CARBON_COPY_ORG_ID")
private Integer carbonCopyOrgId;
@Column(name = "CARBON_COPY_EMAIL_ADDRESS")
private String carbonCopyEmailAddress;
@Column(name = "BCC_ORG_ID")
private Integer bccOrgId;
@Column(name = "BCC_EMAIL_ADDRESS")
private String bccEmailAddress;
@Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
private Integer projectId;

//getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class EmailNotificationQueueRow implements Serializable, IEntity<Integer> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_QUEUE_ID")
private Integer emailQueueId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
private int emailId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "REQUEST_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date requestDate;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "MESSAGE_SENT_FLAG")
private String messageSentFlag;
@Column(name = "MESSAGE_SENT_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date messageSentDate;
@JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMAIL_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private EmailNotification emailNotification;

//getters and setters
}
```

Whenever I set the relationship of the emailNotification variable to FetchType.LAZY (as above) the class is not woven. It is registered for weaving but never is.

The log is below. The EmailNotification entity is weaved but not the EmailNotificationQueueRow entity. Any ideas?

```
[EL Config]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.642--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--The access type for the persistent class [class persistence.model.EmailNotification] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.674--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--The access type for the persistent class [class persistence.model.EmailNotificationQueueRow] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.674--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--The target entity (reference) class for the one to one mapping element [field emailNotification] is being defaulted to: class persistence.model.EmailNotification.
[EL Config]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.689--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--The alias name for the entity class [class persistence.model.EmailNotification] is being defaulted to: EmailNotification.
[EL Config]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.72--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--The alias name for the entity class [class persistence.model.EmailNotificationQueueRow] is being defaulted to: EmailNotificationQueueRow.
[EL Finer]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.736--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--Class [persistence.model.EmailNotification] registered to be processed by weaver.
[EL Finer]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.799--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--Class [persistence.model.EmailNotificationQueueRow] registered to be processed by weaver.
[EL Finest]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.799--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--End predeploying Persistence Unit iDMS_Persistence_Unit; session file:/C:/idms/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_iDMS_Persistence_Unit; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.908--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--Begin weaver class transformer processing class [persistence/model/EmailNotification].
[EL Finest]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.924--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--Weaved persistence (PersistenceEntity) [persistence/model/EmailNotification].
[EL Finest]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.924--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--Weaved change tracking (ChangeTracker) [persistence/model/EmailNotification].
[EL Finest]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.986--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--Weaved fetch groups (FetchGroupTracker) [persistence/model/EmailNotification].
[EL Finest]: 2011-02-15 14:21:13.986--ServerSession(1191324)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--End weaver class transformer processing class [persistence/model/EmailNotification].
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="iDMS_Persistence_Unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/dms</jta-data-source>
    <class>persistence.model.EmailNotification</class>
    <class>persistence.model.EmailNotificationQueueRow</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update**

I am using the eclipselink javaagent string to start up tomcat. Also there are other OneToOne mappings that are lazy loaded in my project that get weaved. Its only this one class (EmailNotificationQueueRow) that doesn't get weaved.

Comment: Can you try if setting ` nullable` on the JoinColumn or `optional` on the OneToOne to false changes anything? Also, which version of EclipseLink are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused.  You say you are using a Java EE application in Tomcat?  I don't understand, Tomcat is just a web container, not a Java EE server?

A compliant Java EE server will allow for weaving of managed JPA Entities during deployment, but Tomcat is not a Java EE server.

I'm not sure starting Tomcat using -javaagent will work with the way that Tomcat loads classes.  I think you must use static weaving with Tomcat, or perhaps use Spring.  Not sure how you have some classes working?  Are you sure they are being dynamically weaved?  Probably is related to how Tomcat is loading the classes, are they deployed in the same way?

Comment: A javaagent can intercept all classes as they are loaded and so allows dynamic weaving even in a java se environment. See for example http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Configure_Dynamic_Weaving_for_JPA_Entities_Using_the_EclipseLink_Agent

Comment: I ended up using static weaving. The weird part was the dynamic weaving was working with the javaagent on other classes but no the EmailNotificationQueueRow. With static weaving it did work on all of the classes. Still unsure why but I'll chock it up to Tomcat not being JEE compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you added the **EclipseLink agent** to the jvm, using the jvm parameter

```
-javaagent:eclipselink.jar
```

For more information, please have a look at the [EclipseLink documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Configure_Dynamic_Weaving_for_JPA_Entities_Using_the_EclipseLink_Agent)

Comment: Unfortunately I already am. Elsewhere in the project I have some lazy loaded one to one mappings and they work just fine. Its just the EmailNotificationQueueRow entity doesn't get mapped. I'll update my question to include this info....

Answer (score 3):

What about Tomcat load-time weaving? I think it's the best way. I successfully use it with Tomcat  6/7.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa
Chapter
"12.6.1.3.1. Tomcat load-time weaving setup (5.0+)"

Comment: Here is an update to the current documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa-setup-lcemfb

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete solution to enable [dynamic weaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307579/jpa-weaving-not-enabled-while-running-test-cases/18360167#18360167) in your project, it also shows how to enable static weaving as well.