# JPA - Weaving not enabled while running test cases

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an application that uses Eclipselink 2.5, and when running the Junit test cases, I always receive this warning:

```
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2013-08-19 01:14:05.142--ServerSession(14351551)--
Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [currentTransit]
for the entity class [class ......persistent.entity.BPExecutionEntity] since
weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

So, I wrote a 'weaving' task on my Ant build file like this:

```
<target name="define.task" description="New task definition for EclipseLink static weaving">
    <taskdef name="weave" classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask"/>
</target>
<target name="weaving" description="perform weaving" depends="define.task">
    <weave  source="D:\...\dist\${ant.project.name}.jar"
            target="D:\...\dist\woven-${ant.project.name}.jar"
            persistenceinfo="D:\...\lib\persistence.jar">
        <classpath>
        </classpath>
    </weave>
</target>
```

OK, everything works, and when I compile the code it generates a woven file half the size of the compiled jar. But, when I run the tests of the project then I still receive the same warning `blah blah blah... since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.`

Anybody knows how to remove this warning from my tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved the situation using dynamic weaving. As I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1, I went to the `Project Options | Run | VM options` and added this text: `-javaagent:C:\eclipselink\jlib\eclipselink.jar`, you can change the address to whatever address you have located the eclipselink.jar.

Then I added this line to the `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
```

That's all. This configuration enables dynamic weaving to execute test cases and removes the `[EL Warning] Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute...etc.`

Comment: in eclipselink 2.6.2 (the latest version as of today) using value="true" will throw an exception when eclipselink tries to load the persistence.xml file. You will have to use one of the following values: "null", "false", "static". According to the API docs using "static" should do the job we want. However, I tried using "static" but I still get this warning. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that static weaving is used in your persistence.xml properties.  See 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

"Step 2: Configure persitence.xml" for details

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for your answer. Yes, I already have `<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>` in the persistence.xml but it's still showing the warnings when running the tests. Recently figured out that the Junit engine does not use the jar file generated in /dist/ folder to run the tests, so there's no point in weaving the jar file for testing. Seems like the solution for this is using dynamic weaving.